# PyQt Connect to KeyPressEvent

Tags: python, events, pyqt4, signals-slots

Certain widgets will allow me to do:

```
self.widget.clicked.connect(on_click)
```

but doing:

```
self.widget.keyPressEvent.connect(on_key)
```

will fail saying that the object has no attribute 'connect'.

I know that sub-classing the widget and re-implementing the `keyPressEvent` method will allow me to respond to the event. But how can I `.connect()` to the keyboard event thereafter, or otherwise said, from a user context?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but keyPressEvent is not a slot so it can't be connected. You have to handle it using any of the event handlers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a custom signal, and emit it from your reimplemented event handler:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super(MyWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        self.keyPressed.emit(event.key())
...

def on_key(key):
    # test for a specific key
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        print('return key pressed')
    else:
        print('key pressed: %i' % key)

self.widget.keyPressed.connect(on_key)
```

(NB: calling the base-class implementation is required in order to keep the existing handling of events).

Comment: Do you not need to overide `__init__` and call the super's `__init__`?

Comment: @wesanyer. No. Python always automatically calls `__init__` on each base-class, regardless of whether it has been overidden or not. But of course, if you **do** override `__init__`, you will then have to explicitly call the base-class implementation as well (because it will no longer be called automatically).

Comment: what is on_key in this context?

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs. It's a slot that is called when the signal is emitted. In PyQt/PySide, a slot can be any python callable.

Answer (score 6):

The way I've done this in the past is (it is a work around), where this is in the sender and the receiver declares/connects to the signal.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('MYSIGNAL'))
```