# Select data point in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I have the following problem: I would like to display a heatmap of several ROIs with their time course using PyQtGraph. This works beautifully using the `pq.image` function. However, I would like to click on a heatmap pixel and then, the corresponding ROI (np array row) should be returned.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I think probably via Qt directly, but a solution inside PyQtGraph would be preferrable.

Thanks a lot for your help, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code available here it's not exactly clear to me, but I think you might just need to override your heatmap's `mousePressEvent` method, similar as in this example for key events: [PyQt Connect to KeyPressEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475940/pyqt-connect-to-keypressevent)