# pyQt5 : issue updating editable ComboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a problem with this piece of code.

`projList` is a variable of type `list`. `self.projPicker` is an instance of `QComboBox`.

```
    self.projPicker.addItems(projList)
    self.projPicker.currentTextChanged.connect(self.itemListChange)

def itemListChange(self,value):
    self.projPathLbl.setText("Project :   " + value)

def itemListUpdate(self):
    comboItems = []
    for item in range (self.projPicker.count()):
        comboItems.append(self.projPicker.itemText(item))
    print(comboItems)
```

With this code, when I add text in in the combobox the `self.projPathLbl` is updated with the `itemListChange()` function each time I type a character .
My problem is, it doesn't work the same way with the `itemListUpdate()`.
With this function, I need to hit the Return key to the update to be effective.

How can I update my `self.projPathLbl` label the same way I update my `comboItems` list ( validating it with the Return key )?

Comment: have you tried the `editTextChanged` signal ? i'm not sure about the difference between them

Comment: and how do you connect the itemListUpdate ?

Comment: itemListUpdate is triggerde with a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one way to do that would be to implement QComboBox as a custom class with an implemented keypress event like here: [PyQt Connect to KeyPressEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475940/pyqt-connect-to-keypressevent)

In the keypress implementation you can filter the enter key and emit your signal, which you can connect to the itemListChange slot.